# If my footage is 15fps, why does Premiere try to create a 29.97 fps sequence when I create a sequence from it?

Tags: premiere, framerate

I'm editing some footage from Eecamm's Skype recorder.
The footage appears to be 15fps 1280x720.  In Premiere CC 2019, when I drop it onto the New Sequence icon, the sequence automatically generated is 29.97fps.  Surely this should be 15fps or 30fps?

Comment: Because it is a standard frame rate. I am sure you can choose a different preset, though the last time I used Premiere it required to set project properties before dropping any videos on timeline, and also it was not very flexible regarding values, basically only allowed me to choose from several presets.